# Where can I get the SharePoint SDK for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, sdk

I want to interact with my SharePoint 2013 Foundation environment.
For my purpose I need the CSOM in my application.
But I cant find the SharePoint SDK for **Windows Phone 8.1**. Cant find any information on the Microsoft / msdn sites.

Update:
I do not want to use the REST API.

Answer:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/efd12f11-cdb3-4b28-a9e0-32bfab71a419/windows-phone-81-sdk-for-sharepoint-csom?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Answer (score 1):

CSOM is a translation of the SharePoint webservices to C# code.

When developing for Windows Phone I would recommend to use the default SharePoint API (webservices) directly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164060(v=office.15).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Well, the CSOM is a very comfortable wrapper for these webservice calls. I dont really want to miss it...
It is fact that there is an SharePoint Windows Phone 8.0 SDK. But I cant find any information about future plans and releases.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see either any SharePoint SDK for windows 8.1 rather only avaible for windows 8.
did you try to work with SharePoint SDK for windows 8?

[This SDK installs SharePoint client libraries and templates for Windows Phone 8](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36818)

Comment: I installed this SDK on my computer at work. But I can't compile it within a Windows Phone 8.1 project.

Comment: are you using the C# or VB?

Comment: I am using C# with Visual Studio 2013 Update 2

Comment: The assembly is outdated: Type universe cannot resolve assembly: Microsoft.Phone, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24eec0d8c86cda1e.